# RCBD analysis using lmer: mixed model is rank deficient

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have, two cultivars, seven nitrogen treatments, randomly applied in each rep. each treatment is a split application at two time periods. I am trying to see the effect, if any, on yield, from the treatments, their timings, and cultivars. After running the model I get a warning message that says "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 36 column/coefficients" and after putting the model through Anova from the car package I do not get results from all explanatory variables and interactions.

Treatment structure:
N rate, kg/ha

```
Trt  GS25   GS30
 1    56      56
 2    34      78
 3    78      34
 4    112     0
 5    0       112
 6    78      0
 7    0       78
```

below is the structure of the data from one location...

```
> str(OR17)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   42 obs. of  9 variables:
$ Year    : num  2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 ...
$ LOC     : chr  "OR" "OR" "OR" "OR" ...
$ Cultivar: chr  "Flavia" "Thoroughbred" "Thoroughbred" "Flavia" ...
$ Plot    : num  101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 ...
$ Trt     : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 2 3 1 4 6 1 5 2 4 ...
$ GS25    : Factor w/ 5 levels "0","30","50",..: 4 2 4 3 5 4 3 1 2 5 ...
$ GS30    : Factor w/ 5 levels "0","30","50",..: 2 4 2 3 1 1 3 5 4 1 ...
$ Rep     : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ yield   : num  80.2 22.6 23.6 112.9 117.3 ...
```

The model:

```
 MMOR17<- lmer(yield ~ Cultivar*GS25*GS30 + (1|Rep), data=OR17)
> summary(MMOR17)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: yield ~ Cultivar * GS25 * GS30 + (1 | Rep)
   Data: OR17

REML criterion at convergence: 235.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.68361 -0.59172 -0.08651  0.51705  1.79272 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Rep      (Intercept)  32.93    5.739  
 Residual             135.23   11.629  
 Number of obs: 42, groups:  Rep, 3

Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                   106.450      7.487  14.218
CultivarThoroughbred          -56.635      9.495  -5.965
GS2530                          1.498      9.495   0.158
GS2550                         10.395      9.495   1.095
GS2570                        -14.826      9.495  -1.561
GS25100                         7.429      9.495   0.782
GS3030                          4.665      9.495   0.491
GS3070                         -5.807      9.495  -0.612
CultivarThoroughbred:GS2530    -6.605     13.428  -0.492
CultivarThoroughbred:GS2550    -3.231     13.428  -0.241
CultivarThoroughbred:GS2570     7.463     13.428   0.556
CultivarThoroughbred:GS25100   -6.952     13.428  -0.518
CultivarThoroughbred:GS3030    -6.850     13.428  -0.510
CultivarThoroughbred:GS3070     2.041     13.428   0.152

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 14 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
     vcov(x)     if you need it

fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 36 columns / 
coefficients
```

Anova output:

> Anova(MMOR17, type=2)
>       Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

```
Response: yield
                      Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Cultivar           254.8904  1    < 2e-16 ***
GS25                 9.6161  4    0.04742 *  
GS30                 0.5423  2    0.76248    
Cultivar:GS25        1.4912  4    0.82820    
Cultivar:GS30        0.2833  2    0.86792    
GS25:GS30                    0               
Cultivar:GS25:GS30           0               
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

as you can see, some of the DF do not properly match as well.

I would also like to see the effect of the treatments as a whole. So would I be correct in just adding that variable to the model like so:

```
MMOR17<- lmer(yield ~ Cultivar*Trt*GS25*GS30 + (1|Rep), data=OR17)
> summary(MMOR17)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: yield ~ Cultivar * Trt * GS25 * GS30 + (1 | Rep)
    Data: OR17

REML criterion at convergence: 235.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.68361 -0.59172 -0.08651  0.51705  1.79272 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Rep      (Intercept)  32.93    5.739  
Residual             135.23   11.629  
Number of obs: 42, groups:  Rep, 3

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                116.845      7.487  15.606
CultivarThoroughbred       -59.866      9.495  -6.305
Trt2                       -14.704      9.495  -1.549
Trt3                       -20.556      9.495  -2.165
Trt4                        -2.966      9.495  -0.312
Trt5                       -10.395      9.495  -1.095
Trt6                       -25.221      9.495  -2.656
Trt7                       -16.202      9.495  -1.706
CultivarThoroughbred:Trt2   -1.332     13.428  -0.099
CultivarThoroughbred:Trt3    3.845     13.428   0.286
CultivarThoroughbred:Trt4   -3.721     13.428  -0.277
CultivarThoroughbred:Trt5    3.231     13.428   0.241
CultivarThoroughbred:Trt6   10.695     13.428   0.796
CultivarThoroughbred:Trt7    5.272     13.428   0.393

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 14 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
             vcov(x)     if you need it

fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 336 columns / 
coefficients
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)
```

Anova:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: yield
                          Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Cultivar               254.8904  1    < 2e-16 ***
Trt                     14.3922  6    0.02555 *  
GS25                             0               
GS30                             0               
Cultivar:Trt             1.5172  6    0.95834    
Cultivar:GS25                    0               
Trt:GS25                         0               
Cultivar:GS30                    0               
Trt:GS30                         0               
GS25:GS30                        0               
Cultivar:Trt:GS25                0               
Cultivar:Trt:GS30                0               
Cultivar:GS25:GS30               0               
Trt:GS25:GS30                    0               
Cultivar:Trt:GS25:GS30           0               
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I tried to be clear as possible and give as much detail as I can. My next step after this is a post hoc analysis using lsmeans.

Comment: you are fitting too complex models for the number of observations . GS25 and GS30 have 5 levels,  Cultivar has >=2, and Trt has 7. You are trying to estimate 5*5*2(or more)*7 fixed coefficients from 42 observations.

Comment: Please try to make the issue less chemistry-related by removing tech details and more programming-related. This will increase the chances to get an answer. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve